# How to integrate $\frac{\cos x-\cos2x}{1-\cos x}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to find $$\int\dfrac{\cos x-\cos2x}{1-\cos x}\ dx$$

I have tried solving the question using substitution. how do I solve it?

Comment: use the tan-half angle substitution

Comment: @lab, how sure are we that the OP means $\cos 2x$ when he writes `cos2x`, and not $\cos^2 x$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, As $$\cos x-\cos^2x=\cos x(1-\cos x)$$ is evne simpler than the current one:)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : In this case that's not a good idea. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: can you explain me please why not? this is the simplest form of the integrand

Comment: "use the tan-half angle substitution" No thanks.

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

$$\cos2x-\cos x=2\cos^2x-1-\cos x$$

Now $$2c^2-c-1=(2c+1)(c-1)$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we have $$\int\frac{\cos x-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\cos x-2\cos^2x+1}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\cos x-2\cos^2x+1}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\cos x-\cos^2x+1-\cos^2 x}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\cos x(1-\cos x)+(1-\cos^2 x)}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\cos x(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x}dx+\int\frac{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos x}dx$$
$$=\int \cos x dx+\int (1+\cos x)dx$$
$$= \sin x +x+\sin x+C$$
$$= 2\sin x+x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your integrand is equal to $$1+2\cos(x)$$

Comment: i don't really understand why the $-1$ is given